# cs50 pset3: runoff, tabulate function- unsure on preferences[i][j] implementation

Tags: c, cs50

I am unsure on how to allow the tabulate function to update each candidates number of votes in relation to preferences[i][j], I understand what the function is here to do, just not the syntax behind it. Here is the code I have written presently. Thank you for taking your time to read.

```
// Tabulate votes for non-eliminated candidates
void tabulate(void)
//run through each of the voters preferances[i][j]
{
    for( int i=0; i< voter_count; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j< candidate_count; j++)
        {
        //update each of the vote counts for candiates still in
        if(candidates[i].eliminated == false)
          {
            preferences[i][j]=i;
            candidates[i].votes++;
            break;

           }

        }

     }
        return;
 }
```

Comment: What kind(s) of answer are you expecting from people who do not know what "cs50 pset3: runoff, tabulate function" is supposed to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to increment the votes of the candidate who is still in the run and of highest preference.

The following code will solve your problem

```
void tabulate(void) {
  for (int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++) {
      // update each of the vote counts for candiates still in
      if (candidates[i].eliminated == false) {
        candidates[preferences[i][j]].votes++;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return;
}
```